# react-google-places-autocomplete Component can't submit form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, google-places-autocomplete

i used to save in base Form made with Mui and would like to Implement a Google AutoComplete Component and submit it in base , i actually successed with the implementation of :

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete apiKey="xx-xx"/>
```

But to Submit my form im force to get my informations from

```
<TextField
         required
                  fullWidth
                  multiline
                  rows={5}
                  id="description"
                  label="Description"
                  name="Description"
                  type="Description"
                  autoComplete="Description"
                  {...register("description", {
                    required: true,
                    pattern: {
                      message: "Please enter a valid Description ",
                    },
                  })}/>
```

of Mui .
So the Question is , how can i get the information of My Component GooglePlacesAutocomplete and submit it throw the TextField
Sorry if its seem a Dumb question im a beginner .

Comment: I didn't understand well what you are trying to do, but I think that autoComplete take only boolean fields (true,false)

Comment: i want to submit an address , i used to get the information from textfield but now im getting the address from googleautocomplet and no i gett address with the autocomplete